# Error running npm install: .node-gyp/6.14.4/include/node/v8.h:21:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, node-gyp

I am running npm install from macos for one of the node project

npm -version
3.10.10
node -v
v6.14.4.

however, while performing npm install i am getting below error:

**.node-gyp/6.14.4/include/node/v8.h:21:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found

## include **

tried updating npm version
npm unstall & npm install node-gyp
npm install -g npm

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading to MacOS Mojave (10.14)

Assuming you're using a Mac with a version higher than 10.7, update the key *MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET* to your OS version in the file *common.gypi*

This fix was originally mentioned here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1574

https://github.com/AlexVentura/node/commit/a80901c79da64fc7ddf0de14542a92700166006f